# Compound assignment and add operator overloading

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, compound-assignment

I need help with both of my operator overloading functions presented below. I'm unsure of how I can implement this without actually using the assignment in the function definitions.

Code for operator + in my .cpp file:

```
MyString& MyString::operator +(const MyString& rhs)
{
  delete [] String;
  String = new char[rhs.Size];
  Size = rhs.Size;
  // needs to be a loop for cascading + 
  // so that String1=String2+String3+String4 will work
  for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1 ; i++)
  {
    //  String[i] + rhs.String[i]; ???
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Code for += operator in .cpp file:

```
MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& rhs)
{
  delete [] String;
  String = new char[rhs.Size];
  String = String + rhs.String;
  return *this;
}
```

Call from main.cpp:

```
 String1 = String2 + String3 + String4;
 String1.Print ();

 String2 += String3;
 String2.Print ();
```

I know my .cpp file codes are wrong, some insight would be great!

Comment: If you are deleting the string before attempting to append to it, you're not going to get very far...

Comment: What do you actually need the + and += to do, append the string?

Comment: I need the + operator to concatenate two strings (where String1 =String2+String3+String4 works) and I need += to be able to operate String1 += String2 meaning String1= String1+String2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, usually you return a new object from `operator+`, because the expectation is that calling + on an object does not change the object itself.

```
MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& rhs)  
{  
  // ...

  return MyString(...);  

}
```

Note the missing reference (`&`) from the return type: you are returning the new object by-copy, not by-reference.

Second, if you `delete` the `String` at the beginning, you will not be able to copy its contents.  Consider this for `operator+`:

```
char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size + 1]; // +1 for the terminating '\0'      
for(int i = 0; i < Size ; i++)      
{
  // copy the contents of current object buffer, char-by-char
  tmp[i] = String[i]; 
}
for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++) // +1 to copy the terminating '\0' as well
{      
  // copy the contents of other object buffer, char-by-char
  tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i]; 
}
MyString result;
delete[] result.String;
result.String = tmp;
result.Size = Size+rhs.Size;      

return result;
```

`operator+=` is a bit more tricky, because you need to manipulate the current object's buffer:

```
char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size + 1]; // +1 for the terminating '\0'      
for(int i = 0; i < Size ; i++)      
{      
  tmp[i] = String[i]; 
}
for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++) // +1 to copy the terminating '\0' as well
{      
  tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i]; 
}
delete[] String;
String = tmp;
Size += rhs.Size;      

return *this;
```

Update: I assume you also call `delete[]` in the class destructor -- which you should.  It is also not hard to imagine, you will want to perform assingment from one `MyString` object to another.  This will lead to cosider the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): If you need any one of desgtructor, copy-constructor or assignment operator, you most likely need all three.

Comment: +1 for clear examples.  You need to swap the indices in the 2nd `for` loop in each function, however: you need `String[i+Size]` and `rhs.String[i]` in both cases.

Comment: when I tried this I got the following error: MyString.cpp:59: warning: reference to local variable âresultâ returned                               and the output was O! ????

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I tried the new code you've provided and it actually concatenates part of the second string and the third string but completely omits the first string. Is this for a cascading execution such as String1= String2+String3+String4??

Comment: Did you notice the missing refernce (`&`) from the `operator+` signature in my answer?  I will update to make it more clear

Comment: aha! It works, it works! Thank you sooo much! one more question: Does this effect the += function much, because now the + operator works perfectly, but the += is doing something funky like Hello Worlda- o World...and it should be Hello WorldHello World...any suggestions?

Comment: and yes you are correct in your update I have implemented all 3 :)

Comment: You should keep the reference for the `+=`.  Other than that, I'm not sure why you would get incorrect results.  Also, if you get `+=` right, you should notice the similarity between the implementation of the two operators and follow David Rodríguez - dribeas's suggestion and implement `+` by means of `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way is to implement the functionality in `operator+=` and then use that to implement `operator+`. Assume for starters than your `operator+=` is correctly implemented, then `operator+` is trivially implementable as a free function:

```
MyString operator+( MyString lhs, MyString const & rhs ) {
   lhs += rhs;
   return lhs;
}
```

Note: The first argument is passed by value, so that it is a *copy* of the original that we can modify through `operator+=`. There are some other tips you might find useful [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/operator-overloading.html).

Now back to implementing `operator+=`, the first thing that you should understand is what the operations that you need to perform are: you need to allocate a longer buffer, copy from the old buffer, append the `rhs` string, swap the old buffer and the new (which contains the result) and free the old buffer. The order of the operations is important, if you release the old contents before copying (as you are doing) then you can no longer copy from that.

```
// Rough approach
MyString& operator+=( MyString const & rhs ) {
   char * new_buffer = new char[ Size + rhs.size + 1];       // [1]
   std::copy_n( String, Size, new_buffer );
   std::copy_n( rhs.String, rhs.Size + 1, new_buffer+Size ); // [2]
   swap(String, new_buffer);                                 // [3]
   Size = Size + rhs.Size;
   delete [] new_buffer;
   return *this;
}
```

[1]: Allocate the new buffer and copy to it. Note that in this particular case the code is *correct* because none of the rest of the instructions in the function can throw an exception. If that was not the case, the new buffer should be managed through RAII to ensure at least the minimal exception safety.

[2]: Assumes that as an invariant of the type `MyString` there is always a null terminator. The `Size+1` in the count argument will copy all elements and the null terminator.

[3]: At this point all the operations have been performed, we can exchange the old and new buffers, update the size and release `new_buffer` (that actually refers to the old buffer)

Comment: Is it necessary to return *this?