# Is there where I use an assignment operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, assignment-operator

I'm very new to classes and while I have all other code written, I am stuck lacking some implementation at the end of two of my member functions.

Here is my header:

```
class bignum
{
public:
// Constructors.
bignum();
bignum(int num_digits);
bignum(const string &digits);
bignum(const bignum &other);

// Destructors.
~bignum();

// Assignment operator.
bignum &operator=(const bignum &other);

// Accessors
int digits() const;
int as_int() const;
string as_string() const;
void print(ostream &out) const;
bignum add(const bignum &other) const;
bignum multiply(const bignum &other) const;
bool equals(const bignum &other) const;
int PublicNumberTest;

private:
// Pointer to a dynamically-allocated array of integers.  

int *digit;

// Number of digits in the array, not counting leading zeros.

int ndigits;
}; 
#endif
```

and here is one of my member functions:

```
bignum bignum::multiply(const bignum& other) const{
bignum product;
bignum row;
int carry = 0;
int sum = 0;
int j = 0;
int *temp_row = new int[];
for (int i = 0; i < ndigits-1; i++){
    carry = 0;
    temp_row[i] = 0;
    for (j; j < other.digits - 1; j++){
        sum = digit[i] * other.digit[j] + carry;
        temp_row[i + j] = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    if (carry>0)
        temp_row[i + j] = carry;
    row = row operator+temp_row //This is what I don't understand. How can I 
        product = product.add(row);  //assign the contents of temp_row?

}
}
```

There is another, but it is basically the same problem. I have an array that I would like to copy to the contents of and place inside of my...class? I guess? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you want to perform c = a*b or a = a*b? that is, do you intend to multiply two arguments, produce a temporary, and assign it to a third, or do you plan to just multiply the object a by an argument b?

Comment: My intention was C = A*B

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `temp_row[]` as the set of digits for `this` object, you could do:

```
delete [] digits;
digits = new_row;
```

You should probably update `ndigits` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry to be thick, but I've been at this ALL day. Why would I need to update ndigits?

Comment: You only need to update ndigits if the number of digits has changed. Since there is a carry involved, that might happen, or it might not.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of doing that: The "old" way, which should be very similar to calling the destructor then the copy constructor:

```
bignum& bignum::operator=(const bignum& other)
{
    delete[] digit;
    ndigits = other.ndigits;
    digit = new int[ndigits];
    for (int i = 0; i != ndigits; ++i) {
         digit[i] = other.digit[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

code which can be also written as:

```
bignum& bignum::operator=(const bignum& other)
{
    this->~bignum();
    new(this) bignum(other);
    return *this;
}
```

This old way is now discouraged because not exception safe.

The "new" way, which is exception safe: you define a swap() member method that never throws any exception and use it to implement the operator=():

```
void bignum::swap(bignum& other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(ndigits, other.ndigits);
    std::swap(digit, other.digit);
}

bignum& bignum::operator=(const bignum& other)
{
    bignum tmp(other);
    this->swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than work out your multiple digit multiplication, I'm just leaving a couple of things to puzzle out,

> Do you want to perform c = a*b or a = a*b? that is, do you intend to
>   multiply two arguments, produce a temporary, and assign it to a third,
>   or do you plan to just multiply the object a by an argument b?
>
> My intention was C = A*B
>
> Then you need to allocate (new) a destination bignum,

Use the friend operator overload should solve your need; it is common idiom to define binary operators (note that I didn't solve your allocating the right number of digits),

```
friend bignum operator+(const bignum& a, const bignum& b); //in class

//you want to calculate A * B --> C
//you need a temporary place to calculate C, then produce a new C,
bignum bignum::multiply( const bignum& A, const bignum& B ) const
{
    //Your A is this, A.digit[];
    //Your B is other, B.digit[];
    //Yout C is temp, a buffer for calculations,
    bignum temp;

    int carry = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //you don't need this, you have temp.digit[];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->ndigits-1; i++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        temp.digit[i] = 0;
        //what do you want to initialize j to?
        for (j; j < B.ndigits - 1; j++)
        {
            sum = A.digit[i] * B.digit[j] + carry;
            temp.digit[i + j] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        if (carry>0)
            temp.digit[i + j] = carry;
    }
    return bignum(temp); //allocate a new bignum
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161541/overloaded-addition-assignment-operator-in-c-for-two-more-than-two-objects) for an example of how to overload a binary operator...

Doing the way you did has drawbacks (returns a const, can't chain more than two additions togethere), but basically you do something similar, but use the `(this->)` pointer,

```
//you want to calculate A * B --> C
//you need a temporary place to calculate C, then produce a new C,
bignum bignum::multiply(const bignum& other) const
{
    //Your A is this, this->digit[];
    //Your B is other
    //Yout C is temp product, a buffer for calculations,
    bignum temp;

    int carry = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->ndigits-1; i++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        temp.digit[i] = 0;
        for (j; j < other.ndigits - 1; j++)
        {
            sum = this->digit[i] * other.digit[j] + carry;
            temp.digit[i + j] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        if (carry>0)
            temp.digit[i + j] = carry;
    }
    //bignum product;
    //return *this = temp; //do this,
    return bignum(temp); //or you should probably return a new object
}
```

you should probably [return a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377108/compound-assignment-and-add-operator-overloading).